# React & Material-UI CSS Style not applied on the first load

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using React and Material-UI to build a Menu for my navigation. The problem is that when I first load the app with "npm start", the style does not seem to apply to the menu item. It is supposed to have proper paddings around the text, but it is not effective on the first load. The problem is automatically fixed when I reload the webpage. Any idea how to fix it?

```
    <Menu
       id="basic-menu"
       anchorEl={anchorEl}
       open={open}
       onClose={handleClose}
       MenuListProps={{
          "aria-labelledby": "basic-button",
       }}
    >
        <MenuItem onClick={handleProfile}>
           <AccountCircleIcon style={{ color: "grey" }} />
           <ProfileField> Profile </ProfileField>
        </MenuItem>
        <Divider />
        <MenuItem onClick={handleLogout}>
           <LogoutIcon style={{ color: "grey" }} />
           <ProfileField> Logout </ProfileField>
       </MenuItem>
    </Menu>
```

Before:

[first load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2XWs.png)

After:

[second load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChZLg.png)

Comment: Where in the code is padding applied?

Comment: I think the default padding style is controlled by MenuItem. I did not write any code to change the padding.